# How is amorphous computing different from spatial computing?

Tags: distributed-systems, parallel-computing, agent-based-computing

Surely [spatial computing](http://www.spatial-computing.org/) and [amorphous computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_computing) share similarities and overlap. Is spatial computing a subset of amorphous computing? How are the two different?

Comment: Have you read the resources you link to? What is your impression?